position sticky trick about overflow:hidden
Original trick :
https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/exvOda`


        body {
      background: #F5F7FA;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .wrap {
      position: relative;
      margin: 10em auto 30em;
      max-width: 960px;
      overscroll-behavior: contain;
    }
    
    .headers {
      top: 0;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .tracks,
    .scroller {
      display: flex;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    
    .scroller {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .tracks {
      overflow: auto;
      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    }
    
    .scenes::-webkit-scrollbar,
    .scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .track {
      flex: 1 0 calc(22% + 2px);
      scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
    
    .track + .track {
      margin-left: -1px;
    }
    
    .heading {
      height: 50px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      border: solid #fff;
      border-width: 0 1px;
      z-index: 1;
      background: #efefef;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .entry {
      border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
      border-top: 0;
      background: #fff;
      height: 8em;
      padding: 1em;
    }
    
    
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .track {
        flex: 1 0 calc(50% + 7px);
      }
    }
<div class="headers">
    <div class="scroller syncscroll" name="myElements">
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tracks syncscroll" name="myElements">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

    



If you look at the content in this link, the parent element of the element using 'sticky' has a scorll-bar there. Originally, the sticky does not work when the parent element scroll-bar appears, but it is using trick.
Interestingly, if I copy it and use the code there as it is, my code will show scroll-bar, but if I move the scroll to the x-axis, it won't work the same as the original. Can I know why?
One more question, scroll-bar appears on codepen.io , but not on regular browsers. Can you tell me why?

You forgot to add the <div class="wrap">  container from the original code which stands as the reference for the sticky coordinates. - scroll-bar appears on codepen.io , but not on regular browsers. Can you tell me why? which scrollbar(s) are you refering too ? What is your real issue aside this example, what are you trying to do ?
